# MySQL/MariaDB Duplicate Rows to Columns

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, pivot, left-join

I am trying to create a query which will join several tables together and converts the rows from one table into columns.

TableA:

| id | username |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a@a.com |
| 2 | b@b.com |
| 3 | c@c.com |

TableB:

| id | name | phone |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Mike | 123456789 |
| 1 | John | 234567890 |
| 2 | David | 345678901 |
| 3 | Daniel | 456789023 |
| 3 | Kevin | 567890123` |

Output:

| id | username | name1 | phone1 | name2 | phone2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a@a.com | Mike | 123456789 | John | 234567890 |
| 2 | b@b.com | David | 345678901 |  |  |
| 3 | c@c.com | Daniel | 456789012 | Kevin | 567890123` |

In my real world case, I would require only 3 of the phone & name columns (i.e. name1, phone1, name2, phone2, name3, phone3). Not all id's will have an entry. Not all id's that have at least 1 row will have multiple.

I am at a loss on how to build this query and would really appreciate any help getting me going in the right direction. When searching I haven't been able to find a duplicate question with this use case, but would assume one is out there and I am not using the right search terms to find it.

I have tried using a subquery but I am not familiar enough with that to make it work. Same thing with CASE WHEN. Because I don't have a specific value to use in the CASE clause, I couldn't make that work.

Answer (score 0):

You can first assign row numbers detail records, then pivot the dataset with conditional aggregation:

```
select a.id, a.username,
    max(case when b.rn = 1 then b.name  end) name1,
    max(case when b.rn = 1 then b.phone end) phone1,
    max(case when b.rn = 2 then b.name  end) name2,
    max(case when b.rn = 2 then b.phone end) phone2
from tablea a
left join (
    select b.*, 
        row_number() over(partition by id order by name) rn
    from tableb b
) b on b.id = a.id
group by a.id, a.username
```

> In my real world case, I would require only 3 of the phone & name columns

This accounts for maximum 2 detail records per user : you can expand the `select` clause with more `max(case...end)` expressions if you want more, incrementing `rn` along the way.

> Not all id's will have an entry.

The `left join` avoids problem here; such users will show up but with empty detail information.

> Not all id's that have at least 1 row will have multiple.

Related columns will contain `null` values.